# SVG Path Data Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, svg

I am looking for a regex that matches each of the individual values within an SVG path.

```
m4507-396.4c-2.2-3.5-2.6-7.3-0.2-11.4M4545.5-428.7c3.5 1.2 7 2.7 9.9 7.3 5.5 8.3 3.7 20.7 3 22.4-2.6 6.6-6.5 9.4-10.1 12.7-1.6 6-6 4.8-9.7 5.4-3.9 3.5-9.4 4.3-11.8 4.3-11.8 0.1

m3918.1-733.6c-7.7-0.7-18-5.3-23.5-10.5-5.6-5.2-11.6-15.5-12.1-20.5-0.3-3.2 0.4-4.5 3.2-5.7 1.8-0.8 2.6-0.8 7.2-0.6 4.6 0.2 12.9 1.6 13.5 2.2 0.1 0.1-1 2.3-2.6 4.9-4.3 7.1-4.3 7.2-3.6 8.9 0.8 2 4.2 4.7 8 6.6 2.8 1.4 3.6 1.6 6.2 1.6l3 0 3.4-5.4c1.9-3 3.5-5.4 3.7-5.5 0.5-0.2 7.2 10.1 8.5 13 0.7 1.5 1.3 3.6 1.4 5.1 0.2 2.3 0.1 2.6-1.1 3.7-2.2 2-8 2.9-15.2 2.2z

m 3726.1737,-460.61233 36.0937,-2.74129 c 8.4162,-1.4953 14.662,-7.69317 13.4018,-30.15418 -13.0333,-2.66897 -13.7567,-3.44411 -16.7523,-4.56882
```

I have included 3 examples of how the path data might be formatted.

The values may be seperated by commas or whitespace and two values may be 'touching' by the '-' character so it would need to split those as well.

```
 First Path Data Match Example:-         Third Path Data Match Example:-
 Match 1: m                              Match 1: m
 Match 2: 4507                           Match 2: 3726.1737
 Match 3: 396.4                          Match 3:-460.61233
 Match 4: c                              Match 4: -2.74129
                                         Match 5: c
```

So on and so forth. You get the idea. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Regular expressions seems like the wrong tool for parsing SVG, especially path data.

Comment: I need to combine the path data to optimise (strip) the files of as much useless information as possible. The 'm' command needs to be converted to uppercase on joining paths and paths with number value counts greater than two between the command letters need to have an 'l' command appended. I've basically managed to write my own regex through trial and error that matches everything with some commands and values being put into groups which I have applied some basic if statements on to pull out the values. If theres a better solution than regex then it would help to provide an alternative.

Comment: I disagree with putting on hold. It was @DanWilson who introduced a broad interpretation of the question, but that is not part of the question itself. OP did give a concise description of the format he wants to parse (SVG Path Data), a description of the tool he wants to use (RegEx/C#), and good examples of what he wants to match (essentially a lexer). That is why I was able to answer with exactly one RegEx. I challenge anyone to show where I introduced an interpretation to give that answer.

Comment: @ccprog the trouble is you've answered a simplified version of the question. Your answer is correct in some/many cases but to do it exactly right would require a much much more complicated regex if indeed it is possible at all. A good question would also have shown some attempt instead of being just requirements but that's a reason to downvote, not to close.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion. All I asked for was the individual commands and values from the string. @ccprogs answer encapsulates this perfectly on all paths I have tested, I've even indicated his answer as correct and wrote a thank you comment which in turn should clarify the problem for those that are confused. Either way I would say that if anyone wants the ability to manipulate path data as a string that the answer is now tried and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lexer that does not care about semantics is easy:

```
\([mzlhvcsqta]|[\+\-]?(\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?)([eE][\+\-]?\d+)*)\i
```

SVG path data consist of single-letter commands and numbers. Each token is either a command letter:

```
[mzlhvcsqta]
```

Each of them can occur in upper or lower case, therefore the search must be performed case-insensitive (`\i`).

Or it is a number: (split into muliple lines for readability)

```
[\+\-]?            // an optional sign
(\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?)  // an integer or a decimal number
([eE][\+\-]?\d+)*  // the exponential part of the scientific notation
```

The next thing to do would be to analyze the sequence of tokens. For example the count of numbers following a command can vary between 1 and 7, some of them can be any number, others only positive or flags (0 or 1). But that is not part of a *lexer*, and would also probably overly strain what a RegEx can do.

Comment: Something that could improve this answer to help future users is explaining the pieces of the RegEx (i.e what each section does) or why it works in relation to the OP's input.  Right now, this is really only helpful to the OP as a copy and paste solution and no one else.

Comment: Nice try but it doesn't always work. This: a25 25 -30 0 1.50-25 is a valid arc and needs to be parsed as 1 .50 since the sweep flag is not a float.

Comment: Again: It's a lexer, not a parser. Things like M4C2 2 V 5 6.6 7 would also be tokenized. I totally agree that sorting out the sematics need another approach.